# Webpack and SASS issue (React app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a very basic Node.js + Express app doing some server and client side rendering using React. When the Express app returns a React rendered component as a part of its response it comes back to the client with the CSS not applied. Then it quickly flashes to the CSS rendered page. I am kind of stumped as to what is happening and just want the CSS to be rendered immediately... I am kinda new to using webpack & React so any help/explanation will be greatly appreciated.

**index.jade**

```
html  
head
    title="Sample app"
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
body
    #app!= content
    script(src='http://localhost:8080/public/index.js')
```

**App.js**

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) require("../styles/App.scss");

import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**server.js (snippet)**

```
...
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {  
    let content = React.renderToString(<App />);
    res.render('index', { content: content });
});
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Extract Text Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to avoid flash of unstyled text. Pete Hunt (one of the creators of React) [ran into this same issue with Webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/170). From that, sokra (the Webpack developer) created this plugin to extract css into a stylesheet.

Without this plugin, the browser executes things in this order:

- Show html (rendered by server-side React).
- Get Webpack bundle.
- Execute Webpack bundle which inserts style elements in head.

With this plugin, the browser executes things in this order:

- Load stylesheets in head.
- Show html (rendered by server-side React).
- Get Webpack bundle.
- Execute Webpack bundle.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the background too!